# Python version is not updating when I move it up system PATH in windows 10 environment variables

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, pipenv

I'm trying to use python 3.8 in PowerShell(specifically with pipenv, but still doesn't work for cmd) as I am learning about python virtual environments, I also have python 3.9 and 3.7 installed. In a tutorial about Django the instructor changes his version by moving it up the system path though I cant get it to work for me. I've moved both versions up and down multiples times, I have uninstalled and installed python 3.8 and 3.9 and have deleted the paths multiple time already but every time it uses 3.9. Both 3.9 and 3.8 have been installed to my local disk(not in program files)and 3.7 seems to have come with visual studios. I noticed before that 3.8 would install into conda so I deleted anaconda and installed 3.8 again, now the path I want for 3.8 is fine but the system path still doesn't update. I want 3.8 to work system wide but maybe I'm not understanding how this works. just a link on how to fix this would help, I don't know what questions to look up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to configure Python environment variable.

1. You've multi add same variable for python.exe route
2. You didn't configure pip location.
3. After change env variable, you need to close current PowerShell and open new one for check.

Comment: So I'm not sure what you mean on your first point but both variables are different, one is python 39 and the other is python 38. I installed pip with the python installation executable and its supposed to automatically add it to path right? And I do restart PowerShell after I change the variable. I did notice that there's different pip versions in both versions, pip, pip3 and pip38 and same goes for python 39 ,pip, pip3,pip39. I'm new to coding and things like PATHS so I appreciate your response.